# NSLayoutConstraint constant is not updating

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, constraints

I wanna update a constraint if device is iPhone SE.

I have a xib view controller that I add it's view as a subview.

```
    //get the empty view
    let emptyVC = JobsEmptyStateView(nibName: "JobsEmptyStateView", bundle: nil)
    let emptyView = emptyVC.view!
    emptyView.frame = self.view.frame

    self.navigationController?.view.insertSubview(emptyView, belowSubview: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar)!)
```

In JobsEmptyStateView I have

`@IBOutlet weak var headerLabelTopLayout: NSLayoutConstraint!`

I have also tried setting it to a `private var`

[image]

[image]

And then finally I have a class that decides if the device is iPhoneSE

```
class func emptyStateHeaderLabelTopLayout() -> CGFloat? {

    let device = Device()

    if device.isOneOf(smallScreenDevices) {
        if Constants.isDevicePortrait()
        {
            return 200
        }
        return 200

    }

    return nil
}
```

in JobsEmptyStateView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        if let topConstant = Constants.emptyStateHeaderLabelTopLayout()
        {
                //self.headerLabelTopLayout.isActive = true
                print(self.headerLabelTopLayout.constant)
                print(topConstant)
                self.headerLabelTopLayout.constant = topConstant
                print(self.headerLabelTopLayout.constant)
                self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                print(self.headerLabelTopLayout.constant)

        }

    }
```

prints:

```
70.0
200.0
200.0
70.0
```

Why constraint is not getting updated?

Comment: I wonder if it a combination of (1) instantiating an instance of `JobsEmptyStateView` (which is IMHO a poorly named UIViewController), that (2) processes `viewDidLoad`, which (3) updates a `weak` constraint, and *then* (4) uses adds that VC's UIView as a subview in a completely different view hierarchy (and apparently, an unnamed view controller). Beyond updating a constant, what are you trying to do from a high-level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the `wR` `hC` constraint and let only the value of 70

Comment: Why? I wanna be able to use wR hC , for landscape mode.

Comment: Because sometimes my Xcode creates some constraints that I didn't ask it to create, instead of `self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` try `self.view.updateConstraints()`

Comment: I will accept this answer but I gotta admit it is pretty stupid that wR and hC wont work and I have to handle all the cases programmatically

Comment: Did you get your problem solved by doing that? If not,  we can discuss it.

Comment: Yeah, removing them worked. But again that doesn't make sense, wR hC must be overriding programmatically set values after `viewdidload`, so removed them and handle all the possible cases for portrait and landscape programmatically